# How to get the IP address which sent a command to a TIdCommand?

Tags: delphi, indy

Delphi XE2, so I guess that is Indy 10(?).

One server, 10 clients. I would like to get the IP address of the client which sends each command.

Btw, this is a closed LAN and I get to assign the static IP addresses (192.168.1.xxx).

I suppose I could put a .INI file on each machine ot give it a unique number and have it pass that as a prefix to each command (or even pass its own IP address as a prefix).

But I hope that I can simply access some data of the TIdCommand to get the sender's IP address ... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `TIdCommand.Context.Binding.PeerIP` property to get the client IP.

Comment: + 1 and the answer. I gogoled, but probably got Indy 9 which suggested TIdCommand.Thread.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;  Thai answer compiles for me. Thanks